# Why did the fundamental forces of nature break symmetry in the order they did?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, unified-theories

First gravity broke loose, then the strong force and finally there was the separation of the weak and the electromagnetic force? Is this a logical sequence? I guess it has to do with temperature/energy. But why are forces breaking loose with decreasing temperature? And why in this order?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, we don't really know.

It's been conjectured that the strong/electoweak split is associated with particles analogous to W/Z bosons, but of much higher mass. There are [many versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) of this idea, so I won't try detailing them. The important point is that, while we've no observational evidence any of it is true so far, *if* it were true it would go a long way to answering your question. (We wouldn't need to observe them to get supporting evidence; we could instead confirm it through proton decay, although even if it exists [it's rare enough to already rule out some versions of these ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay#Projected_proton_lifetimes).)

It takes a high temperature to overcome the weak force's decay with distance, which happens because of the W/Z bosons' mass; *maybe* the even higher temperature at which it's projected the electroweak and strong interactions' running constants become more or less equal points to the mass of even heavier particle species.

We're even less able to suggest what might cause the *very* high-energy separation of gravity from other interactions. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Relationship_to_gravity):

> At the Planck length scale, the strength of gravity is expected to become comparable with the other forces, and it is theorized that all the fundamental forces are unified at that scale, *but the exact mechanism of this unification remains unknown* (emphasis added).

This should be unsurprising, since we don't even know how to quantize gravity yet. ([We](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) [ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity#Other_theories), but we can't yet back them up in the same way we can our account of other interactions.)

But hopefully, we'll one day be able to know rather than merely guess some answer like the following:

"Each interaction becomes weaker at a low enough temperature if that runs afoul of some characteristic mass scale. However, electromagnetism has no such mass scale, so its strength doesn't diminish at the final cutoff, i.e. it's stronger than the weak interaction at low energies. They are both, however, much weaker than the strong interaction, due to sharing a common response to a much higher cutoff at which they separate from it."

Comment: Thanks for the effort in trying to explain this to me (and others). Appreciate it.